# What is the "symplectic duality" between holomorphic symplectic manifolds? Where can I read more about it?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I'm recently working on something called *3d mirror symmetry* in QFT literature, which involves two hyperkähler manifolds. 
There seems to be a corresponding(?) mathematical theory called *symplectic duality*, pursued by Braden, Licata, Proudfoot and Webster.

Where can I read about it? The only thing I could find so far is the proposal [by Proudfoot et al.](http://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/sd.pdf) I'm particularly intrigued by the fifth example in page. 7, which says

> More generally, the moduli space of $G$-instantons on a crepant resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$ is dual to the moduli space of $G'$-instantons on a crepant resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma'$, where $G$ is matched to $\Gamma'$ and $G'$ is matched to $\Gamma$ via the McKay correspondence.

Where can I read about this duality, in particular the case when neither $G$ nor $G'$ is of type $A$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowhere.  The paper is still in preparation, and looks to be for a few more months at least.  Probably the best document at the moment is this (extremely long) set of [talk slides](http://pages.uoregon.edu/bwebster/austin-dual.pdf) of mine.

I should note: even when there is a paper, there won't be a definition that will tell you (by which I mean someone who studies mirror symmetry from the string theory side) anything new.  Just an observation of a lot of very striking coincidences.

Also, it's not going to discuss the non-type A Mackay example in detail; it's not one of the ones we understand well, we just included it because the physicists [told us to](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611063v2).

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben! I'm looking forward to the full paper ... it's also good to know which string theory paper you had in mind.

Comment: You didn't follow the link?

Comment: Hi, Ben. Do you have more precise statements of, for example, duality between quiver varieties and affine Grassmann ? I am not fully satisfied with your evidences in p.38.

Comment: @Ben I did, thank you. (I meant to write "it was good to be informed which string paper...") 

Comment: I think there is a bit more evidence now (those slides are about a year and a half old now, but it's still a little pie in the sky outside the type A case (where things are pretty well established).  What sort of evidence would be more satisfying for you?

Comment: Oh and Yuji, I should say I just misread your comment; your meaning should have been clear the first time.

Comment: Well, for example, rather than just a bijection between bases, is there an isomorphism between 1) the cohomology of the core of quiver variety, and 2) the intersection cohomology group of the affine Grassmannian ? I want it to be `natural' in some sense, which I do not know how to formulate. And it is not clear to me how this is explained in the framework of Koszul duality, discussed in the earlier part.

Comment: Interesting point. I wonder if anybody looked at the symplectic duality from the viewpoint of integrable many-body systems in the spirit of Nekrasov and Shatashvili. Such duality may unveil some new dualities between various Hitchin-type integrable systems.